# How to search and replace in a file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file like this in names.txt:

```
My name is alex
My name is samuel
```

I want to just replace samuel with boxer

My code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

f = open("names.txt",'r+')
for line in f:
  if re.search(r'samuel',line,re.I):
     print line
     m=f.write(line.replace("samuel",'boxer'))
f.close()
```

even though Print line is printing the line correctly but replacement is not happening in names.txt. Let me know if anybody has any clue

Comment: Do you want to replace exact word or any substring? because `r'samuel'` will return True for `asamuela` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Using a regular expression here is overkill. `.replace()` returns the line unchanged if the replacement text is not present at all, so there is no need to test even.

To replace data in a file, in place, it is easier to use the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html):

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('names.txt', inplace=True):
    line = line.replace('samuel', 'boxer')
    print line.strip()
```