# Code to manipulate data inside a file in python

Tags: python

Data inside text file:

```
GOPU 433 33332.000000
GOPAL 20 22233.000000
RAMU 33 76532.000000
```

Here is a code to modify data inside text file:

```
def modify():
    another='Y'
    while another=='Y':
        print "\nEnter name of employee to modify"
        empname=raw_input()
        import os
        fp.seek(0,os.SEEK_SET)
        for line in fp:
            if len(line)>1:                         #To handle line feed
                e.name, e.age, e.bs=line.split()
                e.age = int(e.age)                  # convert age from string to int
                e.bs = float(e.bs)
                if(cmp(e.name,empname)==0):
                    c=len(line)
                    print "\nEnter new name,age & bs"
                    e.name=raw_input()
                    e.age=eval(raw_input())
                    e.bs=eval(raw_input())
                    import os
                    fp.seek(-c,os.SEEK_CUR)
                    ch="%s %d %f" % (e.name,e.age,e.bs)
                    fp.writelines("\n")
                    fp.writelines(ch)
                    fp.writelines("\n")
                    break
        print "\nModify another Record(Y/N)"
        another=raw_input()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter name of employee to modify: GOPAL
Enter new name,age & bs: PANDEY
24
38374
```

file content becomes:

```
GOPU 433 33332.000000
GOPAL 20 22233.000000
PANDEY 24 38374
```

When I am trying to modify the data of `GOPAL` then it is modifying the data of next employee i.e; `RAMU`.

Didn't know why it is happening?

Please provide me a solution for this?

Comment: Why use `cmp()` when a simple `e.name == empname` would do?

Comment: And you'd normally use `int()` or `float()` to convert input values; not `eval()`.

Comment: He is writing to a file, your default string input from raw_input() should be ok right ?

Comment: @yopy: The `raw_input()` still comes from a user; using `eval()` is rarely the right thing to use when all you want is an integer or float value.

Comment: Modifying pieces of a text file is always a bad idea. It would be better to rewrite it whole (see @MartijnPieters) comment in his answer)

Comment: ya thats correct, eval() is like converting raw_input() to input() right ?

Comment: Yes; `eval(raw_input())` is exactly the same thing as `input()` in Python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping over the file object as an iterator:

```
for line in fp:
```

which uses an internal read-ahead buffer; this means that using `f.seek()` works relative to where the buffer read to, not to the line you are processing right now.

You'd have to use `f.readline()` calls instead:

```
for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
```

would give you the same loop effect without the read-ahead buffer.

Your approach will run into *other* problems however; any change in line size will either not overwrite enough or overwrite the *next* line too. A file will not shrink or grow automatically if the output you write to it does not *exactly* match the line length you are replacing.

Instead, you'll have to rewrite the whole file into a temp file and move that back into position.

Further remarks:

- Use `fp.write()`; `fp.writelines()` will end up writing each character individually. It'll work, but only by chance and slowly.
- Don't use `cmp()` when comparing strings. Just use `string1 == string2`.
- Don't use `eval()` where `int()` or `float()` will do.
- You only need to import a module just once, at the top. Those extra `import os` lines are redundant.

Comment: now ,it's changing the data of the desired employee but when edited employee's name is too long then it's overwriting the some part of name of next employee...:(

Comment: @user3223301 that's the reason why you shouldn't modify text files like that... Martijn is telling you of this problem in his answer

Comment: Can you give me some hint of modifying data using temp file? The main thing is that i didn't want to change the sequence by modification i.e, it should modify data at its place instead of deleting and writing     data at the end

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485916/how-to-search-and-replace-in-a-file-using-python/16485997#16485997 for an example.